# Sorting two different vectors of class object together

Tags: c++, vector

Let's say I have a code like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class player{
protected:
    int agility;
    int strength;
    int accuracy;
    string teamcolour;
public:
    void shoot(){};

};
class playerA:public player{
public:
playerA(int a,int s,int ac){
    agility=a;
    strength=s;
    accuracy=ac;
    teamcolour="Blue";
  }
};
class playerB:public player{
public:
playerB(int a,int s,int ac){
    agility=a;
    strength=s;
    accuracy=ac;
    teamcolour="Red";
  }
};
int main() {
    vector<playerA>teamA{playerA(10,40,15),playerA(25,30,25),playerA(20,15,33)};
    vector<playerB>teamB{playerB(35,22,40),playerB(18,34,26),playerB(45,19,32)};
    return 0;
}
```

I want to make every player use shoot() function starting with the player that has the highest agility and continue with next most agile player. I couldn't find a way to sort these different vectors together and I don't want to create one vector with all the players in it. I want to create two separate vectors that represent two teams.

Comment: you can use `std::sort()` method with custom compare function which uses agility to sort.

Comment: @hacker315 I'm a new learner so I don't have much experience using std::sort() .Can you please demonstrate how can I do this?

Comment: Kindly tick-mark the correct answer, if it helped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define this compare function outside main:

`bool compare(player a, player b){
    return a.agility > b.agility;
}`

and call sort:

`std::sort (teamA.begin(), teamA.end(), compare);
 std::sort (teamB.begin(), teamB.end(), compare);`